# Prove that sequence of probabilities is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

$\xi_1, .. \xi_n, ...$ - independent similarly distributed random variables with symmetric distribution. For any natural $n \ F_n= \sigma(\xi_1, ...\xi_n)$ and $S_n = \xi_1 + ... + \xi_n, \ S_0 = 0$. Prove, that for any $a$ sequence $X_k=P(S_{n-k}+S_k \leq a)$ is a martingale. ($k \in \{0, 1, ..., n\}$)

So we need to prove that $E(X_{k+1}|F_k)=X_k$

$X_k=P(S_{n-k}+S_k \leq a)=P(\xi_1+ ... + \xi_{n-k}+\xi_1+...+\xi_k \leq a)$

$X_{k+1}=P(S_{n-k-1}+S_{k+1} \leq a)=P(\xi_1+ ...+\xi_{n-k-1}+\xi_1+...+\xi_{k+1} \leq a) = P(\xi_1+...+\xi_{n-k}+\xi_1+...+\xi_{k}-\xi_{n-k}+\xi_{k+1} \leq a)$

In last sentence I expressed part that similar to $X_k$ but I don't know what to do with probability... Does anyone know what to do next?

Comment: Should $\ X_k\ $ be some sort of  *conditional* probability?  As currently defined ($\ =P(S_{n-k}+S_k \leq a)\ $), it's not a random variable at all, merely a probability (unconditional) that's just a real-valued function of $\ a\ $.

Comment: we have conditional expected value $E(X_{k+1}|F_K)$, where $X_{k+1}$ is a random variable and probability as it's said in task

Comment: But, *as currently defined*, how on earth is $\ X_k\ $ a random variable?

Comment: Not I imagined this problem, but that's how it was given((

Comment: I expect whoever posed the problem intended to define $\ X_k\ $ as $\ P(S_{n-k}+S_k \leq a\,\vert\,\mathcal{F}\,)\ $ for some $\sigma$-algebra $\ \mathcal{F}\ $, but inadvertently omitted the condition from the probability.

Comment: To illustrate the problem, suppose $\ \xi_i\ $ are standard normal variates (which will satisfy all the conditions specified in the problem as currently stated).  Then, $\ S_{n-k}+S_{k}\sim$ $ \mathcal{N}\left(0, n+2k\right)\ $, so $\ X_k = P(S_{n-k}+S_k \leq a\,)=$ $\mathcal{N}\left(0, n+2k\right)(a)\ $.  Even if you consider the $\ X_k\ $ to be degenerate random variables (i.e. with zero variance), they don't constitute  a martingale for any non-zero $\ a\ $.